# link_to and no route match problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have try to use `link_to` like so:

```
<%= link_to post.title, {:controller => 'posts', :action => 'show', :id => post.title}, :title => post.title %>
```

If title contains  a period (.), I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"show", :id=>"test.title"}
```

But if no period is included, everything works.

Can anyone help me?

I found the solution.http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/101911#222985

Comment: What do you mean "contains point"? Do you mean a period (`.`)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `:title => post.title`  Try using the post object in there instead.

```
link_to post.title, :controller => 'posts', :action => 'show', :id => post
```

or even better

```
link_to post.title, post
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that you linked is the worst one. Overriding rails internals to fit your problem is wrong. I rather use the gem called `friendly_id`, this will creates a url proof slug from your id. It's easy to set up and use.

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Answer (score 0):

It thinks that in the route it is expecting the format ".title" and that has not been configured.  Because your route would look something like this "/posts/test.title" could you not rather use "/posts/test-title" as that is a better url structure for most web servers?

If you do need to hack it, in rails 2 you can use the ":requirements" option like this:

`map.connect '/post/:id/:title', :controller => 'forum', :action => 'show_post', :requirements => { :title => /.*/ }`